# Difference DiskCacheStrategy in Glide v4

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I am using Glide 4.1.1 in one of my android application. I am using it with below code and not facing any issue in application.

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(constant.BASE_URL+"images/"+data.getPicture())
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .dontAnimate()
                .centerCrop()
                .dontTransform())
                .into(holder.imageView);
```

I have doubt in .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) Option. There total five type option located with this like below

```
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
```

I have tried to find its documentation but not able to find difference between this. Let me know if someone have used it and have idea what is difference between this all and when should we use it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 119, accepted):

- Glide 3.x & 4.x: DiskCacheStrategy.NONE caches nothing
- Glide 4.x: DiskCacheStrategy.DATA, Glide 3.x:
  DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE caches only the original full-resolution
  image.
- Glide 4.x: DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE Glide 3.x:
  DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT caches only the final image, after reducing
  the resolution (and possibly transformations) (default behavior of
  Glide 3.x)
- Glide 4.x only: DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC intelligently chooses a
  cache strategy based on the resource (default behavior of Glide 4.x)
- Glide 3.x & 4.x: DiskCacheStrategy.ALL caches all versions of the
  image

Further Read [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics)

Comment: Thanks For Answer. If my image always stay same in server....according your think which should I use ?

Comment: If I were you for your scenario I will go with  DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC.

Comment: Im still confused with v4, im writing the same syntax for this Cache implementation but still got the error.

Comment: Can you help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619895/how-to-get-image-path-which-is-stored-and-downloaded-by-glide-using-url-in-andro?noredirect=1#comment110740243_62619895